# implement "create another like this" functionality in grails

Tags: grails

After saving a new instance of a domain class in grails, I have a "create another like this" button that brings up another create screen where the fields are populated with the  values of the instance I just created.

In the first try, I passed all the existing field values as params in an alternate create button:

```
<g:link class="create" action="create"
    params="[app:volInstance.app.id,
             ass:volInstance.assessment.id,
             name:volInstance.volName,
             type:volInstance.volType.id,
             note:volInstance.volNote,
             recommendation:volInstance.recommendation,
             discovered:volInstance.dateFound,
             url:volInstance.urlParam]">
     Create Another like this
 </g:link>
```

and then doing a lot of `<g:if>` on the next create.gsp to see if the parameters are present.   I then advanced to just sending the instance id as a param

```
<g:link class="create" action="create" 
        params="[vid:volInstance.id]">
```

and changed the create method in the controller. This simplified things (no longer have a huge params list):

```
    def create() {
      if (params.vid) {

        def id = params.vid
        def v = Vol.findById(id)

        params.volNote = v?.volNote
        params.volType = v?.volType
        etc......
      }
    respond new Vol(params)
   }
```

This works nicely and eliminates all the `<g:if>`s but still have a lot of lines of params.x = v.x
would there be a way to get rid of those lines and just pass the object as a param?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a good place for a [`Command Object`](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.0/guide/single.html#commandObjects). You can declare it in your controller, and then pass it as an argument to your action.  You can even add validation if you want.

```
class MyCommand {
    Long id
    String volNote 
    String volType

    static constraints = { 
        volNote (blank: false) 
        //...
    } 
}
```

Then in your action:

```
def create(MyCommand cmd) {
    Long id = cmd.id
    //...
```